# Stripe Payment in IOS App With Error Invalid Request Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, httprequest, stripe-payments

I am working on an iOS app that requires me to make and update recipients using Stripe. When I run the code, I receive the error from the data received: "2014-08-24 17:28:42.962 myapp[1703:60b] data: {
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: sk_test_**********:",
    "param": "sk_test_**********:"
  }
}"

I am unsure why I am receiving this error if anyone could help me out or show me an alternate way to go about sending a request to Stripe to make a new recipient.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients"]];

                             NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:&name=%@&type=individual&card=%@",StripeSecretKey,name,token.tokenId];
                             request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
                             request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                             [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                              {
                                  if (error)
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error);
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"data: %@", response);
                                      NSLog(@"data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                                  }
                              }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending your secret key in the body of your request, when you want to set it as a header instead. Replace your `params =` line with these two:

```
[request setValue:[@"Bearer " stringByAppendingString:StripeSecretKey] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&type=individual&card=%@",name,token.tokenId];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After making the change, I am receiving this error: ERROR: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients,NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients, NSUnderlyingError=0x17efb6d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"} I read online that the error could be due to my SK_KEY but it is correct. I tried to add a ":" at the end but it didn't work. Are you aware of how I could fix this?